# Bootstrap navbar shifts when i add tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a portfolio page to my bootstrap site. When I try to add an additional "row" or even another div class="col-md-12" and refresh the page, the navbar shifts left like 5px:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header"><h1>Work Examples</h1></div>            
    <!--examples begin-->
    <!--<div class="col-md-8">-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>The Daily</h4>
            <p>YahooMedia is responsible for creating, curating and programming quality editorial and entertaining content experiences. We produce original content and work with established publishing partners to deliver inspiring and delightful content to our users. We are the partner that connects any artist, storyteller, great content producer and brand with the audiences it wants and needs at scale, across devices, every single day. From A-list directors and producers to industry-leading editorial voices like Katie Couric and Joe Zee, we are focused on bringing content from today’s biggest creators to our audience.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">yo</div>
          <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    </div><!--row-->
</div><!--container closed -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="container">

<div class = "page-header">
```

Comment: Missing  <div class= "container> berfore the <div class=page-header>